# DRV8874 fault investigation (on one unit only out of 9 sharing the same design)

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have designed a board which controls 9x DRV8874, using the exact same circuit as shown in the datasheet for the independent half-bridge example (except the control input of OUT2 is tied to GND, I'm not using it because of the current sensing topology ; and nFAULT sinks 2mA from a LED off the 5V when it's activated).

When I power up the board while no load is connected, one of the IC has FAULT activated, not the others. I looked at the VCP voltage and they're all at Vmot+5V (17.5V) except one, the one which has a fault, and this one sits annoyingly at Vmot+7.5V (20V). I can also see the CPL and CPH pins oscillate like crazy (respectively between 0.7 and 12.5V, and between 7.5 and 20V) between two values on the faulty unit, whereas they're nice and stable on the others. When I connect a load, the chip whines... I don't know why, and I don't see anything else I could test.

Then, when I disconnect the logic supply (5V and 3.3V), VCP drops to VM which is normal.

The other ICs work as expected, but this one never outputs anything. What's wrong with it?

I checked the entire PCB for shorts, nothing. They all have the same identical schematic and layout, and I populated the board P/N by P/N so no mistake there either.

[image]

Comment: Look carefully at the board itself for possible shorts or opens.  Problems with etching the board can cause opens or shorts on one board, while the rest of the batch is fine.

Comment: Change the chip and be done with it. $hit happens now and then and your time is probably not worth spending on it.

Comment: A single cap charge pump ought to be 2x Vss=5+5V. But yours is a Mystere.  I wonder if the Cap value C1, C2 affects the result.

Comment: So you think the chip's dead? I updated my observations on the CPL and CPH

Comment: ckeck if the charge pump's cap is bad soldered.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: I checked it, and also its value. Everything looks clear... And I'm out of DRV's. Looks like I'm going to have to buy more then.

Comment: Try reducing the cap values, and always buy spares IC’s