# FET H-bridge has slow convergence for the last 10% of output voltage: why? (DRV8874)

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a board with 9x DRV8874, as described in another unrelated thread [there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516143/drv8874-fault-investigation-on-one-unit-only-out-of-9-sharing-the-same-design).

The driver switches fast to 90% of VM when ON (0V when OFF) then converges slowly to the final value (time constant~=100us). When the PWM frequency is increased (but still <40kHz specified), the convergence flattens to an average value which deceively resembles bipolar transistors VCEsat varying with duty cycles. The average voltage applied to the load therefore depends on the duty cycle, which cannot be calibrated easily.

Some snaps of the OUT1 voltage (no load connected, measured straight at the IC pins):

Low PWM freq

[image]

Zoom on top

[image: desc]

Nominal PWM freq

[image]

High-ish freq (sorry, other duty cycle)

[image]

And here is how the average voltage varies not linearly with the duty cycle (nominal freq, CH1 is the motor supply, both cursors are set where OUT ends up being at the beginning and the end of the cycle). Notice how the OFF and ON voltages go up with increasing duty cycles.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think I managed to model this behaviour using the following model. Vs0 is a constant voltage change when switching, so Vs is shifted up by as much as the voltage at the end of the exponential decay. I'm calculating deltaV and deltaVs for each infinitesimal change in duty cycle and I animated a plot changing the duty cycles, and I have a matching behaviour. Does that help locating the cause?
[image]

*(Erratum: k is supposed to be k+1 on the second PWM cycle)*

When a load of 12Ohm is connected these figures barely change (drop due to RdsON).

Where does this come from and how can I remedy to it?

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvsf66

Comment: What is a "pure voltage" and how is it different from a regular voltage?

Comment: Yeah I know that does not exist, but I wanted to stress it was not the RdsON anyone would have jumped onto otherwise. I have updated the title to reflect that. Any ideas ?

Comment: Powersupply is ok, with the load attached?

Comment: Looks like it's indeed due to the convergence... Added snaps. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the Load L, R, values?  It appears to mean if Ron = 0.2 , load R is 9x this hence 90% and inductance L/R=T =  100 us approx. or L=1.8*100us = 180 uH.  With a 50mV current sense R and two probes you could check the current and use the slower clock rate for more torque and current (rms)

Comment: The issue is stated without any load connected - but when there is one, the load is 12R (updated my post). When the load is not connected there is no current through the chip, confirmed by looking at the ISENSE output (c.f. schematic in the link provided).

Comment: I have added yet more information. Still a mystery...

Comment: Have you checked your scope probe compensation?

Comment: Try inputting a regular known-to-be-good square wave. And don't forget to award the bounty to the right person.

Comment: Are you using 1x or 10x probes for measuring?

Comment: @Andyaka Nice one Andy, though when have I let anyone down this way except that one time ;) ?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Totally forgot to check the probe compensation, that's a great lead! I'll check that on Monday, it might be it. Using 10x probes.

Comment: @BruceAbbott: you were right, the scope probes have the same behaviour on the calibration output of the scope. Since you spotted that first, if you write an answer I'll accept it - otherwise I'll accept the answer which is currently there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I am seeing is reverse "droop" caused by un-calibrated oscilloscope probes, or a similar capacitive load at the driver IC (not likely). Could you please verify calibration of your probes, in that they have the square tops and bottoms of a clean square wave. I see no place where else where capacitance, acting to over-dampen the edges of the signal, could happen. Outside of over-dampened snubbers on MOSFET drains or un-calibrated probes, I have not seen this before.

Under-dampened probes and snubbers cause a rising front edge. With little to no dampening you get a leading edge spike, then a fast decaying ring-wave. Please advise what you find after calibrating your probes and testing driver output again.

I am going to study this driver IC to look for bias issues. None found.

Comment: You are absolutely correct - this was indeed the cause, I had forgotten to check the calibration of the probes and it turns out I used another scope's probes by mistake. Nonetheless, Bruce Abbott had spotted this first so I am afraid I am going to have to give the bounty to his answer if he writes one. I've upvoted your answer, for what it's worth though - and thanks a lot for answering because without him, you'd have been there to save the day!